# How to know when multiple API calls are done?

Tags: android

Multiple API calls are executed and each one loads a different section of the screen. What I need to do is to disable a button (to prevent it being clicked multiple times) until all these calls are done (all sections are loaded). How can I know when a group of calls are done?

Comment: You can use Rx Java and you will be notified whenever api calls are done.

Comment: As Karan said  use RXJava for the API calls and to disable a button use button.setClickable(false); in a if statement